# Cannot mount local config for maven in docker multi-stage builds

Tags: docker, maven, kubernetes, jenkins, repository

I using Jenkins with Kubernetes slave. (Kubernetes plugin)

I want to build docker multi-stage. In maven build state I want to use local repository. (config in settings.xml)

I already created configmap on K8S and mounted while running build job.

```
agent {
kubernetes {
  yaml '''
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Pod
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: docker-socket
        emptyDir: {}
      - configMap:
          defaultMode: 420
          name: nexus-xml-test
        name: config-vol
      containers:
      - name: docker-pod
        image: docker:19.03.1
        command:
        - cat
        tty: true
        volumeMounts:
        - name: docker-socket
          mountPath: /var/run
        - mountPath: /root/.m2
          name: config-vol
      - name: docker-daemon
        image: docker:19.03.1-dind
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        volumeMounts:
        - name: docker-socket
          mountPath: /var/run
    '''
}
}
```

And I Already verify that settings.xml is already mounted.

```
2022-09-13 17:27:54  + cd /root/.m2
2022-09-13 17:27:54  + ls
2022-09-13 17:27:54  settings.xml
```

In dockerfile. I added this command.

```
RUN mvn -s /root/.m2/settings.xml
```

But when i build. It cannot find settings.xml

```
2022-09-13 17:45:48  Step 2/10 : RUN mvn -s /root/.m2/settings.xml
2022-09-13 17:45:51   ---> Running in e779f9fcf9b6
2022-09-13 17:45:52  [ERROR] Error executing Maven.
2022-09-13 17:45:52  [ERROR] The specified user settings file does not exist: /root/.m2/settings.xml
2022-09-13 17:45:52  The command '/bin/sh -c mvn -s /root/.m2/settings.xml' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Please help suggest.

Comment: Can you please also add your Dockerfile, at least the part where you define stages in multi-stage and where you copy settings.xml into docker image?

Comment: @m19v I'm still not sure the correct method.
Does it always need to copy settings.xml file. Or is there a way that can be mount settings.xml into docker?

Comment: 1. Both ways, i.e. mounting folder with config files to docker container and copying config gile into docker, are functional. 2. You have to decide what suits in your application case. E.g. if the config file changes continuesly it makes sence to mount the folder with it and adjust whenever you want without building new docker image.